# Rebuild Apk With ApkTool Error

Tags: apktool

Hi guys I trying to rebuild an apk file with ApkTool. The apk is made with Xamarin. And get this error :

[image: error message]

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dir `C:\Users\dragos98g1\Desktop\Apk Tool` to your PATH environment. It seems like can't find aapt.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.

First, make sure the `aapt` and `build-tools` directory is on path. The `build-tools` directory is in the SDK. Here's mine from the latest SDK on Mac OS X:

```
$ find /opt/ -iname aapt
/opt/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/20.0.0/aapt
```

Then:

```
$ aapt
Android Asset Packaging Tool

Usage:
 aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
   List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
...
```

Second, remove the whitespace from the path names. Change:

```
C:\Users\dragos98g1\Desktop\Apk Tool
```

To:

```
C:\Users\dragos98g1\Desktop\Apk-Tool
```